# Repeating functions in javascript (rock, paper, scissors)

Tags: javascript, function, repeat

I'm a beginner in javascript and coding in general and I just made a rock, paper, scissors game where you re-choose if it's a tie.
I want the function to repeat after line 15 (if the condition is true, of course), but I have no idea how to do this...
So if theres's a tie, you're supposed to re-choose (which works), but after the re-choosing, the generation of the computer's choice should be repeated and the same with the compare() function to make the system of re-choosing work.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
 if (choice1 === choice2) {
     console.log("The result is a tie, please re-choose!")
     userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
 } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
     if (choice2 === "scissors") {
         return "rock wins";
     } else {
         return "paper wins";
     }
 } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
     if (choice2 === "rock") {
         return "paper wins";
     } else {
         return "scissors wins";
     }
 } else {
     if (choice2 === "rock") {
         return "rock wins";
     } else {
         return "scissors wins";
     }
 }
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a function for the process of choosing, and then call that in compare:

```
var userChoice, computerChoice;

var choose = function() {
    userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    } 
}


var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        console.log("The result is a tie, please re-choose!")
        choose();                                   // Choose again
        return compare(userChoice, computerChoice); // Compare again, recursively!
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        ...
    }
    ...
};

choose();                             // Make the choice
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);  // Compare
```

Or, if you don't want to use recursion, you could `return "tie";` in case of a tie, and just repeat the process until the tie is resolved:

```
var choose = function() {
    // As above
    ...
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        console.log("The result is a tie, please re-choose!")
        return "tie"; // Tie occurred
    }
    ...
};


var result;

do {
    choose();                                     // Choose an item
    result = compare(userChoice, computerChoice); // Compare the choices
} while(result != "tie");                         // Repeat until ties are resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use recursion:

```
 if (choice1 === choice2) {
     console.log("The result is a tie, please re-choose!")
     userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
     compare( userChoice, choice2 );
 } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
```

Comment: This doesn't generate the computers choice again. _but after the re-choosing, the generation of the computer's choice should be repeated_

Answer (score 0):

I recently started JavaScript at CodeAcademy and came across the same problem,
John's answer is correct albeit it needs a few corrections for it to work.

This part, where we call the choice() and then compare(userChoice,computerChoice) function, the variables userChoice and computerChoice are declared inside the choose function, making them local variable which cannot be called from the last line of the code.

The only change you need to do is that you need to call the compare(userChoice,computerChoice) inside the choose function and then it works just fine!

Here's the complete code that worked for me.

```
   var choice = function()
        {
                var userChoice = prompt("Select rock, paper, scissors");
                var computerChoice = Math.random();

                if(computerChoice<=0.33){
                    computerChoice = "rock";
                }
                else if(computerChoice<=0.67){
                    computerChoice = "paper";
                }
                else{
                    computerChoice = "scissors";
                }
                alert("The Computer's choice is:- "+computerChoice);
                var answer = compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
                alert(answer);


        };

        var compare = function(choice1,choice2)
        {
            if(choice1===choice2)
            {
                alert("It's a tie! You must select another choice!");
                choice();
                return compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
            }

            else if(choice1==="rock")
            {
                if(choice2==="scissors")
                {
                    return("Rock wins! You've won!");
                }
                else
                {
                    return("Paper wins! You lose!");
                }
            }
            else if(choice1==="paper")
            {
                if(choice2==="rock")
                {
                    return("paper wins! You've won!");
                }
                else
                {
                    return("Scissors wins! You lose!");
                }
            }
            else if(choice1==="scissors")
            {
                if(choice2==="paper")
                {
                    return("Scissors wins! You've won!");
                }
                else
                {
                    return("Rock wins! You lose!");
                }
            }
        };
        choice();
```